# Has Sādhna ( Meditation practice) with closed eyes more benefits than with open?

Tags: vipassana, meditation

Nowadays, I've been practicing Vipassana (Sometimes anaapan) with open eyes since I instantly start feeling sensations almost everywhere in my body including flesh & organs when I draw my attention there. Actually, I haven't fixed proper time for Sādhna in my routine rather I try to practice it 24hrs by being aware constantly like during eating, walking, listening, sitting (During activity I try to witness activity with detachment) with **equanimity**.

But whenever I give time to meditation with **closed eyes**, I feel my surrounding very dynamic, beautiful & loving once I open my eyes after meditation.  So far, I have been taking this as **my hallucinations along with ego** is the reason I haven't cared to give dedicated time for meditation practice with closed eyes.

But now, I want to ask whether I'm missing something?

- Should I allot dedicated time for meditation with closed eyes? Are there some benefits?
- Is feeling surrounding dynamic & beautiful after meditation a hallucination?

Answer (score 2):

To your question, **”Should I allot dedicated time for meditation with closed eyes? Are there some benefits?”** I would advice you to do otherwise. Each person is different. In your case it is when you keep your eyes wide open that you are most effective. So put more emphasis on the things that work for you, and that you consider favorable. Now I will give you some pointers to help develop this type of ‘meditation’ to another level.

In interacting with the world, we see visuals (rupa) with eyes, hear sounds with ears, smell odors with nose, taste with the tongue, touch (pottabba) with body, and think about concepts (dhamma) with the mind. Be mindful when you experience these while you are in any of the four main postures of sitting, standing, walking, or lying down. Then you will observe that kamachanda and vyapada are the main culprits for making a mind stressful, and for causing “inside fires”. Try to forcibly remove any thoughts of extreme greed and hate as they come to the mind. Make a habit of it. Then with time you will begin of “cooling down” or experiencing niramisa sukha.

Also in time you will abstain from committing an immoral act at any time. In any posture – be it sitting, standing, walking, and laying flat, you will be vigilant on what you are about to do or speak. This is being “morally mindful” at all times. get into the habit of contemplating their consequences. When thoughts come to mind to say something or to do something while sitting, standing, walking, or lying down, you will to get into the habit of contemplating their consequences. Then with time you will see a change in yourself, a sense of tranquility, a “peace of mind”. When you are at this stage, it will be easier to get into samadhi, even if you are just doing the “breath meditation”.

Answer (score 0):

When meditating some past impressions can surface either pleasant, unpleasant or neutral. Their are like they are like dreams and should be treated so. You should not identify it with ego which always lead to suffering now (any egoistic throught has some sensation associated with it, and whatever the sensation it has suffering as an element of it) and craving which creates future existence hence suffering in the future.

Also keeping eyes closed will be helpful to reduce distractions.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the instruction given to Potthila by seven year old Arahant,"six openings in a mound where an iguana make it home, to catch this iguana, close up the five exits, wait for to come out from last exit." So you will see the benefit of meditation with closed eyes. At the same time, during every day activities, you can do mindfulness practice in every moment.
Our mind is constantly disturbed by lobha, dosa and moha, once coming out of sitting meditation practice, your mind is so calm and undisturbed with Samadhi that clear the delusion previously covered. It is not hallucination.